# Is there any way to enable ansi colors in journalctl logs?

Tags: shell, systemd, colors, journalctl

`foo.py` prints ansi [colored](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) output in my terminal

Now if I execute `foo.py`in a systemd unit and `journalctl --all -u foo.service --output cat -f` all output is monochrome.

How can I journalctl systemd with ansi colors?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `man journalctl` there are two environment variables that might be of help: `$SYSTEMD_LOG_COLOR` and `$SYSTEMD_COLORS`. You could try setting one or even both of those to `true` on the same line before the journalctl command.

However, this relies on journald actually recording the color information. If the above doesn't work, try setting `--output` to `export` to see if the ansi escape sequences for the colors exist in the records.

Comment: Thank you, I tried all your suggestions though without success